# Error 1719 during Office 2010 Silent installation

Tags: vbscript, ms-office, gpo

I have created a logoff vbs script enforced through GPO for a silent installation of office 2010 SP. The main part of the script run the following command:

```
SetupCommand = ShareDir & "\x86\setup.exe /config " & ShareDir & "\x86\ProPlus.WW\config.xml"
ReturnValue = oShell.run(SetupCommand, 1, True)
```

installation files are located on a network share (permissions: full control for everyone). Installation exe has been modified through office 2010 customization tool and proper configuration of ProPlus.WW\config.xml file.

The installation seems to work correctly until installation of updates when it returns error 1719 Windows Installer service could not be accessed, preceded by a warning event 1530:

```
Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.  
DETAIL - 
2 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-682003330-507921405-725345543-4463:
Process 2760 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-682003330-507921405-725345543-4463
Process 2760 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-682003330-507921405-725345543-4463\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

I've tried the script on 5 different hosts and I always get the same error. I've tried once to use the same script at logon and it worked.
If I run the command manually it works.

Do you have any idea why the script is not working at logoff? do you have any workaround to suggest?

Comment: Probably some services that requires to install the SP has been terminated. May be you should move this to Logon instead of Logoff. Patches (*.msp) to office is okay to run during a log off.

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled msi logs, I'm checking it and it is quite verbose, but I've found the following error several times:

DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90001B0410000014.0.4763.1000 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bc70a.msi. Expected product {90140000-001B-0410-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90140000-0015-0410-0000-0000000FF1CE}.

do you have any idea of what does it means? should I share the entire logs?